# how to compare php timestamp with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have:

```
$_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
```

in php.

I'm trying to 'inject' it to jquery:

```
var sesstime = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['CREATED']) ?>;
```

Now i want to current date:

```
var timestampjq = (new Date()).getTime();
```

And how to format these dates ?

I want to use:

```
if(timestampjq - sesstime > 60) {

}
```

Or is it nonsense ?

Comment: What keeps you from comparing these values? Is there anything not working with your approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS - getTime()**

```
The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch.

JavaScript uses milliseconds as the unit of measurement, whereas Unix Time is in seconds.

getTime() always uses UTC for time representation. For example, a client browser in one timezone, getTime() will be the same as a client browser in any other timezone.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

**PHP - time()**

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the
> Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

**Calculation**

So basically, you can do that calculation, just remember that JS is in milliseconds and PHP time is in seconds, so simply multiply the value from php in 1000.

```
if(timestampjq - sesstime*1000 > 60) {
```

**Important notice:** There's might be a difference between the server's time and the browser's time.

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP docs:

> [time()] Returns the current time measured in the number of **seconds** since the Unix Epoch

From the MDN docs for getTime:

> JavaScript uses milliseconds as the unit of measurement, whereas Unix Time is in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use microtime function of PHP as a UNIX date.The TimeStamp of PHP is returned in microseconds.

The Javascript getTime() function return UNIX date in miliseconds.

Then you need to add "000" to your PHP Timestamp if you want to work with it for example as:

$yourPHPTimeStamp= round(microtime(true) * 1000);

I wait help you in anyway ;)